# Ordering a list using VBA based on non-exact values in cells

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to VBA and was hoping I could get some guidance on sorting and ordering.

I have a table of information with about 200 rows and 5 columns. In Column B there is "additional information" and I'm looking to identify which rows have text that contains in part any of the following words: "Training", "Admin", "General" and "Extra Info" and group them together.

So an example would be:
Personal Admin,
Work Admin,
Weight Training,
DD Extra Info,
Training for EAS,
General Write Ups.

So I need to be able to sort and order the whole row based only on part of each cell's value.

Hope that makes sense - I'd really appreciate any guidance!

I've used this custom list in the past to find and sort exact phrases:

```
Dim nCustomSort As Variant
Dim xx As Long

nCustomSort = Array("Training", "Admin", "General", "Extra Info")

Application.AddCustomList ListArray:=nCustomSort

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
.Sort.SortFields.Clear
xx = .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
  With .Range("A1:Z1000" & xx)
  .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(2), Order1:=xlAscending, _
              Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes, MatchCase:=False, _
              OrderCustom:=Application.CustomListCount + 1

  End With
  .Sort.SortFields.Clear
End With
```

Comment: You could create a new column, in the new column place 1 if the corresponding cell in column B is `Like *Training*`, 2 if it is `Like *Admin*`, etc. Sort the data according to this new column, then -- delete this column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's a proposal without helper columns:

```
Option Explicit

Sub sort()
    Dim nCustomSort As Variant, elem As Variant
    Dim LastCell As Range

    nCustomSort = Array("=*Training*", "=*Admin*", "=*General*", "=*Extra Info*") '<--| the order of appearance in this array determines the order of sorting
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        With .Range("A1:Z" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
            Set LastCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).Offset(1)
            For Each elem In nCustomSort
                .AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=elem
                If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Offset(, 1).Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then
                    With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                        .Copy LastCell
                        Set LastCell = .Parent.Cells(.Parent.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, -1)
                        .Delete
                    End With
                End If
            Next elem
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

the drawback is that copying and deleting is a time consuming operation so that if you have many k of rows it may take too long

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I can't seem to get it to work, but there are also no errors presenting, so can't figure out what is wrong. I also just had another look at the table and all the labelling is very consistent - would it be easier to match the exact phrase to say, the first 6 characters of a cell? Rather than any phrase contained within a cell?

Comment: Ah, what it appears to have done is ordered the list in the right way, but in ascending order by the numerical values contained in Column A next to it.

Comment: Ignore the last comment, I was accidentally pointing it to Column A instead of B. It definitely works (so thank you!) but I have no idea why. I'm going to need some more VBA practice,

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you can't use wildcards in custom lists to sort data.

The code below shows a generic substring sorting function which allows case matching and extended arrays of substrings to test.

```
Sub ArraySort()
    Dim CustomSort() As Variant: CustomSort = Array("Training", "Admin", "General", "Extra Info")
    Dim wsSort As Worksheet: Set wsSort = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim SortRange As Range: Set SortRange = wsSort.UsedRange
    SubstringSort SortRange, 2, CustomSort, True, True
End Sub

Function SubstringSort(SortRange As Range, _
    SortColumn As Long, _
    SortArray() As Variant, _
    Optional Header As Boolean, _
    Optional MatchCase As Boolean) As Boolean

    ' SortColumn is the column index within the SortRange to sort via substring lookup
    ' SortArray is the array of substrings to search for

    If IsMissing(Header) Then Header = False
    If IsMissing(MatchCase) Then MatchCase = False
    Dim ScreenUpdating As Boolean: ScreenUpdating = Application.ScreenUpdating

    On Error GoTo ExitFunction

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim PadLen As Long: PadLen = Len(CStr(UBound(SortArray) + 1))
    Dim Col As Range, Index As Long, i As Long, Cell As Range

    With SortRange
        Set Col = Application.Intersect(SortRange, .Columns(SortColumn))
        If Col Is Nothing Then Exit Function

        For Each Cell In Col
            Index = UBound(SortArray) + 1
            For i = 0 To UBound(SortArray)
                If MatchCase = True Then
                    If InStr(Cell.Value, SortArray(i)) Then Index = i
                Else
                    If InStr(LCase(Cell.Value), LCase(SortArray(i))) Then Index = i
                End If
                If Index <> UBound(SortArray) + 1 Then Exit For
            Next i
            Cell.Value = String(PadLen - Len(CStr(Index)), "0") & Index & "#" & Cell.Value
        Next Cell

        .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(SortColumn), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=Header, MatchCase:=MatchCase

        For Each Cell In Col
            Cell.Value = Right(Cell.Value, Len(Cell.Value) - InStr(Cell.Value, "#"))
        Next Cell
    End With
    SubstringSort = True

ExitFunction:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = ScreenUpdating
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply - I feel like this is way over my head! I'll start working through it and try to understand the different parts and see if I can get it to work with my spreadsheet.